# Installing apps into sd-card(External storage)

Tags: android, installation, android-sdcard

I was trying to set my default install location of android apps into my sd-card(external storage).So i tried these commands,

adb shell pm getInstallLocation (this shows 0[auto])

so i run this command to make it sd-card

adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2

again i run this to see if the command ran successfully or not.

adb shell pm getInstallLocation (this shows 2[external)

But after all these still my apps are getting installing into internal memory and i am getting low memory space issue in my phone.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you tried with installLocation="PreferredExternal" options in your manifest.xml file ?

If you try this your app will get installed in external storage.

Comment: then after installing you need to move to sdcard.. you will get this option in Settings->Appliatons -> manageApplicatons-> particular applications- > you will be having an option like move to phone and move to sdcard option.. by using that you can change it .

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the **installLocation** in your Manifest.xml?

Please see also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html